# Having trouble to run the Google Drive API on Google Chrome

Tags: google-drive-api

Here I am again still trying to run my platform with the Google Drive API. It works perfectly on Mozilla, but it does not work on Google Chrome. I keep getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
at initClient (google_drive:370)
at api.js:15
at fa (api.js:8)
at A (api.js:15)
at Array.r. (api.js:15)
at Object.x. [as loaded_0] (api.js:15)
at cb=gapi.loaded_0:1

Here is the code I am running:

```
            var CLIENT_ID = '';
            var API_KEY = '';           
            // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
            var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest"];
      
            // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
            // included, separated by spaces.
            var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly';
      
            var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
            var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');
            var localdriveButton = document.getElementById('localdrive_button');
            
      
            var FILES = {};
      
            function handleClientLoad() {
                setTimeout(function(){ gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient); }, 3000);
            }
      
            function initClient() {
                gapi.client.init({
                    apiKey: API_KEY,
                    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
                    discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
                    scope: SCOPES
                }).then(function () {
                    // Listen for sign-in state changes.
                    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
        
                    // Handle the initial sign-in state.
                    updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                    authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick();
                    signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick();
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
                });
                
                return gapi;
            }
```

Does anyone have any idea of what problem I might have and how to fix it?

Comment: How are you running it? Local server? When you say it works from Mozilla, what works exactly? What are you trying to do? Have you followed the steps in the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js)?

Comment: So... we are trying to pull or files and folders from Google Drive into the platform we build. We are running it on our server but it only works when we use Mozilla Firefox... it doesn't work anywhere else.. We tried the quickstart but it's still not working!

Comment: You are serving the HTML and JS content from a server, and getting those pages from your local computer? Are you absolutely sure that you are running this code too? `<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>` because the error would suggest that the library didn't load properly

Comment: Yes! That's the case! We checked again and we are running that code. We still have no idea why we are getting the message! Thank you for your help! Any other idea of why we might be getting that?

Comment: I think you'll need to add more details about how you have set this up, because as it stands this is not reproducible.